# ORDER BY using custom priorities for text columns

Tags: oracle

This is a sample table:

```
name | cat
----------
hugo | sal
bob  | mgr
mike | dev
jeff | mgr
john | dev
```

Both `name` and `cat` being Varchar.

`cat` reflects a category for these names, but I like to assign a priority to them, followed by a query to list them all, ordered by this priority.

What ways are possible? I could extract `cat` into a second table, build a foreign key etc. But given my app is very simple and the structure might be non-changeable: What possibilities do I have to list the `mgr` names first, followed by the `dev` names, followed by the `sal` names?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming you can't change your structure, you can use a CASE statement in your ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY case cat when 'mgr' then 1 when 'dev' then 2 else 3
```

If you *can* change your structure, however, you can create a `Category` table including the category code and a ranking, join your sample table to the `Category` table and sort by this ranking.

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY (case when `cat` = 'mgr' then 1 
when `cat` = 'dev' then 2 
else 3 end)
```

This structure help me in Wordpress. For example to select custom posts first theh other: poster and project  is custom
 SELECT `post_type` FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY (case when `post_type` = 'poster' then 1 when `post_type` = 'project' then 2 else 3 end)

Comment: Note that a) the brackets are optional: a `case` *expression* (as this is called) is valid anywhere a column can be specified; and b) the expression can be slightly simplified to `case \`cat\` when 'mgr' then 1 when 'dev' then 2 else 3 end`